# How to edit a firebase timestamp in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a timestamp for example `June 29, 2022 at 12:00:00 AM UTC+7`. By displaying this timestamp into a string I get `Timestamp(seconds=1656608400, nanoseconds=0)`. However before sending this to firestore, I'd like to change the time into `June 29, 2022 at 06:00:00 PM UTC+7` for example.

I am currently using `CalendarSelectionDetails.date` from syncfusion_flutter_calendar in order to receive the selected date, however the time is defaulted to 12AM, and I have another drop down menu to select the time. I'd like to update the default time to the time selected in the drop down menu.

Is there a way to convert it to a string and edit the string and convert it back to timestamp, or should I calculate how many seconds I'm off from the selected time and add it to timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i have made a simple function that can do that for you

you can call it where ever you want

```
updateTime(DateTime date){
  DateTime inputDate = DateTime(date.year,date.month,date.day,6,date.minute,0,0,0);//replace the 6 with the value u want to update it to
  Timestamp newResult = Timestamp.fromDate(inputDate);
  print("Your new time stamp is $newResult");
  return newResult;
}
```

here is how you can use it

```
updateTime(Timestamp.now().toDate());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was really confused with the syntax.

Comment: i am glad its helpful